# GDPR own consent dialog

Tags: java, android

I want to update my app due to Google EU User Consent Policy (https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/dfp/android/eu-consent). I'm using DFP mediation so I can't use Google-rendered consent form. In this case, how do I make my own consent dialog? I can get list ad providers but I don't know what to do next.

```
List<AdProvider> adProviders = ConsentInformation.getInstance(context)
                                                 .getAdProviders();
```

Comment: You should tell at least what do you *want* to do in general.

Comment: M. Prokhorov: I'm updating my app due to Google EU User Consent Policy (https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/dfp/android/eu-consent) and I want to show a dialog like Google-rendered consent form (https://developers.google.com/admob/images/android_eu_consent_form.png)

Comment: That's fine and all, but don't you think that would make a good addition to your actual question?

Comment: M. Prokhorov: Oh sorry, I just edited my question

Answer (score 0):

You should create your custom dialog with custom items or use any library and put that list into a recyclerview.
I used this code for mine:

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout);

TextView dialogTitle = dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogTitle);
RecyclerView recyclerView = dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogRecyclerView);
Button dialogConfirm = dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogConfirmButton);

dialogName.setText(title);
RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

Adapter dialogAdapter = new DialogAdapter(adProviders);
recyclerView.setAdapter(dialogAdapter);

dialogConfirm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    });
dialog.show();
```

Comment: You mean just show list ad providers in dialog? And if user click confirm, call below code to set ConsentStatus.PERSONALIZED?

        ConsentInformation.getInstance(context)
    .setConsentStatus(ConsentStatus.PERSONALIZED);

Comment: you can do whatever you want, either click on single item provider to show others information like in another dialog

Comment: One more question, if I use DFP mediation with FAN as my third-party ad network, what code should I add to pass consent to FAN? If Unity ads is my third-party ad network, I can find some line of code to add from https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/dfp/android/mediation/unity#eu_consent_and_gdpr . But with FAN I can't find any addition code